# Quick switching of data in plist

Tags: ios, info.plist

I'm working on client-server iOS app and save server url in the app properties plist. I often have to switch from running server on my local machine and staging server.

How can I quickly switch the data in the plist file or even plist file itself in the xcode project?

Answer (score 0):

Key the URLs differently. 
Use some launch condition or a setting in your build conditions of some sort to determine which one to use.